# OneDrive Screw Up (How to Repair)

Tags: windows, sync, onedrive

Long, weird, story.

We ordered a laptop. It has a short: shocks us, completely crashes, and reboots. We’re sending it back.

We ordered an AIO as a replacement. Works fine.

Wife had stuff on the laptop. She hand moved most of it to the AIO. OneDrive synced everything it had from the problem laptop to the new AIO. She did a week’s worth of new work on the AIO … and this is key for down below … added, deleted, and moved files and subfolders in its OneDrive folder.

Needed to get all personal information off the laptop before returning. But the laptop has not been on for a week, so it is not synced to her OneDrive.

I powered on the laptop. I unlinked OneDrive on the problem laptop. For all I know, it accomplished some synching while I was doing that.

Backed up most of the personal stuff to a thumbdrive just to be sure. Then I deleted those folders from the unlinked problem laptop. This included folders from the OneDrive folder. Paused for a while.

In the meantime, the problem laptop did its shock, crash, and reboot thing … and there was a setting in place to start OneDrive on a reboot.

So it synced, deleting the matching files and folders from OneDrive.com and from the new AIO (while my wife was watching from the other end of the house).

We both got the popup from OneDrive that there was a lot in its recycle bin, and did we want to restore it. Before we could coordinate, my wife did a restore on the AIO, which then repopulated the AIO and the problem laptop.

Here’s the thing. It is obvious that OneDrive got confused. Almost all of it is fine, but there are some discrepancies that are obvious to us. This seems to be mostly a problem of files and subfolders.

Following block lays out the architecture giving us problems.

- Let folders be single letters: A, B, C, etc.
- Let subfolder be two or more letters: AA, AAA, BB, BBB, CC, etc.
- Let files end with numbers

  - Files in the root would be numbers 1, 2, 3, etc.
  - Files in a folder would be the folder with a number, so: A1, AA1, B1, etc.

I think this describes the initial setup of the problem laptop.

It has two files, 1 and 2, and two folders, A and B, in its root.

A contains two files A1, A2, and two subfolders AA, and AAA. Each subfolder contains two files, so AA1 and AA2 in one, and AAA1 and AAA2 in the other. B is organized the same way.

In the AIO, a file was deleted and added in the root. In folder A, a file was deleted and added in a subfolder, while a subfolder was also deleted and added. In folder B, files were only moved around.

Like so (it would be great if someone can fill in the blank columns):

```
Initial Laptop  AIO After a Week    AIO After Deletion from the Laptop  AIO After Deletion from the Laptop and Restore from the AIO

1               1       
2           
                3       
A               A       
   A1                  A1       
   A2           
                       A3       
   AA                  AA       
      AA1                     AA1       
      AA2               
                              AA3       
   AAA          
      AAA1          
      AAA2          
       AAAA     
          AAAA1     
          AAAA2     
B               B       
   B1           
   B2                  B2       
                       BBB1     
   BB                  BB       
      BB1                     BB1       
      BB2               
          B1        
                              BBBB      
                                 BBBB1      
                                 BBBB2      
   BBB                 BBB      
      BBB1              
      BBB2                    BBB2      
          BB2       
   BBBB             
      BBBB1                 
      BBBB2
```

This is all kind of mind-boggling. Anyway, I know that what OneDrive restored to the laptop does not match the back up that I’d made a few minutes before. And, OneDrive does not appear to have properly restored everything from the AIO back to itself. I know what OneDrive will do when I delete a file from the laptop that’s in the same location on the AIO.

1. If the file has moved, when it is deleted from the laptop will OneDrive find it on the AIO and delete it (what happens to B1)?
2. If the folder has moved, when it is deleted from the laptop will OneDrive find it on the AIO and delete it (what happens to BBBB and its contents)?
3. If the files in the folder have changed, and I delete the folder from the laptop, will OneDrive delete the folder with different files in it from the AIO (what happens to A)? If I then restore that, how will it handle the discrepancy in files (what happens to AA3 — we do have some files that look like they may have just been dumped to the root).
4. What other possibilities am I missing??

Comment: So what exactly is your question?  Your table is unreadable

Comment: "OneDrive got confused" - I don't think it was OneDrive that got confused.

Comment: Four questions at the bottom. Fifth question is whether or not you even read that far down.

Comment: Admit that table is difficult to understand; it maps out folder hierarchy on two systems in simplified form. Yes, I am very confused; been using MS cloud synchronization since Windows Live Mesh, and I am not used to having OneDrive sync when it was not running at all when I left it. Asked this question on more than one site. Snark to content ratio is highest here. :(

Comment: If you are returning the laptop why not simply wipe it with a system reset or just kill Onedrive to stop it making things worse and then [restore Onedrive](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/restore-your-onedrive-fa231298-759d-41cf-bcd0-25ac53eb8a15) to clean it up?

Comment: That is what I'm doing. But the damage is done, so I have to fix it. The main reason for not throwing in the towel and resetting is that I'm not sure the laptop was adequately backed up and transferred to the AIO in the first place. So I always make a back up before a wipe.